# Controls missing from Visual Studio drop down using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, events

I've recently started using C# after years of using VB.NET

When using Visual Studio, using VB.NET, on the code behind files (.aspx.vb) i could select from a list of controls in my markup file (.aspx) and then select an event to automatically put into my code behind.

I've noticed with C# I don't get this option:

[image]

Why is this? Or is my intellisense just playing up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135299/microsoft-visual-studio-and-c-how-to-visually-add-events-to-controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c# you can't add events like vb.net project, two dropdowns in C# project for class and its methods. you have to use property window to add events or double click on the controller it will add default event for the control.

Comment: Another piece of VB functionality that I can't believe hasn't been written for C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a list of `Events` you will need to be on the form, not in code behind.

Select the `Form` right click, go to Properties, at the top of the Properties bar you will see a lightning bolt, click this and you will see all available events for that Form.

Comment: Is there no way of doing this from code behind rather than having to go to designer?

Comment: You can do it in code but you have to know what the control's exposed events are first. All the designer does is make the process simpler.