# need help in a program to make church management program in vb2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, listbox

I im doing a program to make a church management for my final year project of school, I have divide all the families that belong to the parish, and in each family there's several members (dad,mother,son,daughter,etc), I have the families divided my cods(famaly1,famaly2,famaly3) and also each family have a surname eg (Smith,Jones,Jackson)

now i know who ever uses the program will not know all the cods for all the family´s and i bet that the family's will not memorize there family cod so i want to make the search mode this way:

if the person search for the family cod then they will see 
[image]

if the person searchs for the family surname they will see

[image]

now what i want to know its how i can program the list box? because when i double click on the list box when coding i can only program what happens when the user clicks on the list box and i cant program what will happen when the user clicks on the surname

thnx for any help

Answer (score 0):

When you "double click" on the listbox using the visual editor, Visual Studio will generate the code-behind for the 'click' event for listbox.

Instead what you need to do is handle the ListControl's [SelectedValueChangedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx)

That event is triggered when a user clicks on any ListControl Item.

The MSDN link I posted above has sample code to hookup to the event.

Comment: can you tell me how to use that cod because when i past it in vb nothing happens

Comment: You still need to hook up the method to the actual event. This question (first answer) shows how to do that in visual studio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135299/microsoft-visual-studio-and-c-how-to-visually-add-events-to-controls

Comment: i still dint get it cant u pls make it and upload it and send me the download link