# determine if item is selected in C# ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am developing a windows forms application and load the list from this code:

```
private void showList()
    {
        TeamTableAdapter teamAdapter = new TeamTableAdapter();
        lstTeamName.DataSource = teamAdapter.GetTeamsActive();
        lstTeamName.DisplayMember = "TeamName";
        lstTeamName.ValueMember = "TeamID";

    }
```

I want to enable a button if the user selects one of the items.  What event should I put the code into.  I the following code but the event seems to fire before the user clicks on the list.

```
 private void lstTeamName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstTeamName.SelectedIndex > -1)
            btnImportXML.Enabled = true;

    }
```

I moved my code to the SelectedIndexChange event but it still fires before the user selects an item and the selectedIndex is 0.

Comment: Maybe `SelectedValueChanged` or `SelectedIndexChanged`?  There are lots of events to choose from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You dont want to bind to the `Click` event but to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. You should be able to accomplish this by simply double clicking on the Control in designer.

Comment: I moved my code to the SelectedIndexChange event but it still fires before the user selects an item and the selectedIndex is 0.

Comment: Did you wire up the event handler?

Comment: What version of Vs are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135299/microsoft-visual-studio-and-c-how-to-visually-add-events-to-controls

Comment: I know how to wire up an event handler and I don't think the version of VS is relevant.

Comment: Ok if you say so - But you obviously haven't wired up the correct event handler else the event wouldnt fire until the Index changes

Comment: If you re-read my question that is what I am asking.  Not how to wire up an event handler.

Comment: I dont need to re-read it - I and a couple of other people have told you that the event you need to wire up is the SelectedIndexChanged event or even the SelectedItemChanged event. The link I posted above provides a pictorial walkthrough on accomplishing this. If you are still struggling then the help you need is beyond this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that you don't want to bind to `Click` as that will likely fire too early.

I recommend you look into the `DropDownStyle` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle(v=vs.110).aspx.  If you set that to `DropDownList` then the `SelectedItemChanged` will fire and `SelectedIndex` could be `> -1`

If you leave it as the default `DropDown` then you may want to use `TextChanged` and check the `Text` property.