# Drawing in child window - C#

Tags: c#

My problem is how to draw a simple line in a child window in C#, i.e. :

- I have a parent window, with a button. Clicking the button, a child window shows,and a line is drawn on it.

Well, how do I do that ? This is my code for child window:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Pen pen;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    }


    private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g;
        g = this.CreateGraphics();
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does not work for you ? Child window does not show up, the line does not show up, etc.

Comment: @Adrian Faciu The child window shows up, but the line is not drawn.

Comment: Your code from above should work as it is. Please post the part where you handle the button click and show Form2.

Comment: @Adrian Falciu This is the code:

Comment: namespace Test
   {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
         Form f2;

         public Form1()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            f2 = new Form();
            f2.ShowDialog();
         }
       }
    }

Comment: You can edit the question and add the additional info there. Also look at CzBiX question from the comments. I still don't see any error with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is better:

```
private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black))
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

use the graphics instance from paint event, and **using** syntax to auto dispose pen object

Remeber call **Show** method in parent window like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: @EB Does you write **Form2_Paint** method by hand? you may not register event in Designer file by GUI Designer.

Comment: Did not write by hand. I registered the event in the usual way.

Comment: @EB how about try draw line in parent window, so make sure `DrawLine` is worked as you want.

Comment: I guess I've found a solution: I create "new Pen" and Graphics in parent window (Form1). In child window class (Form2), I declare a Pen and Graphics variables, I add a constructor and I pass the variables Pen and Graphics from the parent window. And it works. Sorry, I can't edit the whole code because my reputation (:-)) is to low. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: And I forgot to write that in the child window class I added Form_Load like this :                                               private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form2_Paint);
}

Comment: The key point is you aren't registered paint event before, so the `Form2_Paint` is never called. look here, [How to add events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135299/microsoft-visual-studio-and-c-how-to-visually-add-events-to-controls)

Comment: Thank you. I used the tip and it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @EB please mark my answer as accepted if you think it's worked for you. see [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)