# Retrieving values for first and second column in row selected by user

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

When a user click on the any record `DATAGRIDVIEW1` so the value of Column(0) "ID and column(1) "Name" automatically captured and displayed in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the simple code which helped me to get the value from `DATAGRIDVIEW`

`row.Cells(1).Value.ToString`
My code for the project

```
` Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_SALARY.CellContentClick
    Dim rowmemory As String
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DGV_SALARY.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    rowmemory = e.RowIndex
    ADD_NAME_TXT.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
    ID_TXT.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
    Call SALARY_NAME_SEARCH_CMD("SALARY_SEARCH_QUERY")
    With DGV_SALARY
        .Rows(rowmemory).Selected = True
        .Refresh()
    End With

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[DataGridView.SelectionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1)". This might help you.

```
private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, "firstname1");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2, "firstname2");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3, "firstname3");
    dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}

private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count >= 1)
    {
        string id = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
        string firstname = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(firstname + " with id " + id + " selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: ITS VB .NET project buddy sorry I forgot to mention please re-explain it in VB .net

Comment: ok but there is another problem 'e.rowindex' is not working in selectionchaged event

Comment: How are you adding the event? Use this post to learn how to add events in visual studio. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135299/microsoft-visual-studio-and-c-how-to-visually-add-events-to-controls